# P&T Assets target added elements

Tags: add-on, css, assets

I wish to change the styling of a list of Asset files. 
See https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34921860/styling%20example.pdf

Since the elements are added using Javascript the html and css changes cannot easily be inspected using Firebug.

Wrapping the Asset-field in a div with id="nn", makes it possible target the inserted table with *div#nn table* and change the background to a dark colour. So far so good.

However, the list that appears when right-clicking on a row needs also to be restyled and div#id ul does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That context menu gets added to the end of the DOM with the class 'assets-contextmenu'. Assets only targets it using ".assets-contextmenu", so even adding a "ul" before that ("ul.assets-contextmenu") in your CSS selectors would be more specific.

Here’s what its DOM looks like:

[image: Assets context menu DOM]